# Developing BlackBerry app with 3rd party content

Tags: blackberry

I'm working on a BlackBerry app, however I'm loading data from various 3rd party websites around the web. (E.g, posts from stackoverflow or currency rates off Yahoo.com) I'd like to know if this could cause any trouble, would it be allowed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's what those sites are for. If that was a problem, then the Firefox guys would be in serious trouble because Firefox does that too. Google couldn't release Chrome, since it does that too. (IANAL; this is not legal advice.)

Answer (score 1):

How are you pulling data from these sites?  Are you signing up to use there tools available to developers?  Have you even investigated if these sites offer any tools.

**Get clarification from each site**

Each site should have a contact email if you look hard enough, and direct your question there.  It is better to ask now, then to find out that you have a lawsuit on your hands...

My comments should not be be taken as legal advice.

Answer (score 0):

As a lawyer to check out the end user and/or developer and/or api licenses and agreements that each of the sites provides. If what you're doing falls within the limits of those licenses, then you're ok, if not, then you might get into trouble.